# Telerik/ Kendo MVC Grid, Load grid on demand, not on page load

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik, grid, modal-dialog

i found a couple examples on how to do this, and none of them are working for me.

**Here is my Telerik MVC grid:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PlayerStatsViewModel>()
    .Name("PlayerStats")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.PlayerId);
        columns.Bound(o => o.FirstName);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.PlayerId))
    .Read(read => read.Action("PlayerStats_Read_Bound", "Contest").Data("getPlayerId"))      
    ).AutoBind(false)
    )
```

**Open modal with my grid**

I set autobind(false) which prevents page load. After a user clicks a link i open a modal with my grid, and need to pass in a parameter.

```
// open modal
$(document).on("click", "#openStatsModal", function () {
    playerId = $(this).data('id'); // get parameter from click
    loadPlayerStats();
});

function getPlayerId() {
    return {
        playerId: playerId
    }
}
```

**Make ajax call?** 
My click method works and i get my player id. Then i try and make my grid call.

```
function loadPlayerStats() {
    var grid = $("#PlayerStats").data("playerStats");
    alert(grid); // returns undefined
    //grid.ajaxRequest(); this didnt work either
    grid.dataSource.read(); // Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined
}
```

**Action method**
Never gets called unless i turn off autobind

```
public ActionResult PlayerStats_Read_Bound([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int playerId)
        {
            // some code
            return Json(result)
        }
```

Comment: You are using the selector on the grid incorrectly, `var grid = $("#PlayerStats").data("playerStats");` should be `var grid = $("#PlayerStats").data("kendoGrid");` (assuming that `PlayerStats` is the correct ID of the HTML element you wish to render the kendo grid on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
var grid = $("#PlayerStats").data("kendoGrid");
```

and then:

```
grid.dataSource.read();
```

Comment: This works, as does $("#PlayerStats").getKendoGrid(); Not sure why as I've seen examples in official docs using variable names. Not sure what "kendoGrid" maps to.